# Qt ComboBox + Searching XML + Printing out data from XML to GUI

Tags: c++, xml, qt

**Update**

```
void MainWindow::readXml()
{
    QDomDocument Champions;
    QFile xmlFile("champions.xml");
    xmlFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    Champions.setContent(&xmlFile);

    QDomElement root = Champions.firstChildElement();
    QDomNodeList ChampionNames = root.elementsByTagName("Champion");

    for(int i = 0; i < ChampionNames.count(); i++)
    {
        QDomNode championNode = ChampionNames.at(i);
        if(championNode.isElement())
        {
            QDomElement Champion = championNode.toElement();
            ui->comboBox->addItem(Champion.attribute("Name"));
}}}
```

Managed to get something like this so I've the names in the comboBox now :)

I'm new to this community so I'm happy to meet all of You!

First I want to inform You that I'm pretty new to Qt programming however I've had some basic c++ lessons in school though it was only console programming and I've never worked on stuff like that. Why I've started with Qt? It looked easy to me and hell it was compared to visual studio! So here is my problem.

Basiclly I have a comboBox where I would read my "Name="" " attributes in. There will be around 100 maybe abit less maybe a bit more don't know Yet. I don't know how to start with everything this since I have never done such thing before. What i want the software to do is basiclly when i select a "name" in the combobox, i want all the attributes ("Q" "W" "E" "R") to be printed out in the 4 labels as You can see on the little image I've added.

I don't know if I need to first read the file into some strings arrays or data structures. Do I need to search the XML file for the "Name" which is selected in ComboBox and then somehow print it out? I spent some time on this but I cant find a way to achive the thing I want. I would really appriciate some code exemples specially using the ComboBox since as said I'm new to this.

XML File looks like this in case image is blurry:

```
<ROOT>

 <Champ Name="XXX1">
  <Q>QQ1</Q>
  <W>WW1</W>
  <E>EE1</E>
  <R>RR1</R>
 </Champ>

 <Champ Name="XXX2">
  <Q>QQ2</Q>
  <W>WW2</W>
  <E>EE2</E>
  <R>RR2</R>
 </Champ>

</ROOT>
```

I'm really bad on describing things so I've made a small ilustration using a pen to let You understand me better :)

[My beautiful sketch.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI008.jpg)

Thanks for Your support in advance! Hope I'm clear enought with my question. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should represent your `XML` data as a C++ class/struct:

```
class Champ {
public:
   // A constructor using QDomElement as argument
   Champ(QDomElement element);
   QString name;
   QString q, w, e, r;
};
```

Second you should load the XML file, parse it, and populate a vector (or map) with `Champ` objects.

```
QVector<Champ> loadChampsObjects(const QString& xmlPath)
{
    QVector<Champ> champObjects;
    QFile file(xmlPath);
    if (!file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return champObjects;

    /* QDomDocument takes any QIODevice. as well as QString buffer*/
    QDomDocument doc("mydocument"); 
    if (!doc.setContent(file)) 
        return champObjects;

    //Get the root element
    QDomElement docElem = doc.documentElement(); 

    // get the nodes we need
    QDomNodeList nodeList = docElem.elementsByTagName("champ");

    // Check each node create a Champ object and add it the vector...
    for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.count(); i++)
        champObjects.append(Champ(nodeList.at(i).toElement()));

    return champObjects;
}
```

Third populate the `QComboBox`. We will use the index in vector as `userData`:

```
QVector<Champ> champObjects = loadChampsObjects("path.to.xml");
for (unsigned i=0; i<champObjects.count(); i++)
    pComboBox->addItem(champObjects[i].name, QVariant(i));
```

Finally in the slot connected to the `currentIndexChanged` signal of combo box you can easily access the properties of the selected object using the `userData` that indicated the index in the vector:

```
void champObjectChanged()
{
    unsigned vectorIndex = pComboBox->itemData(pComboBox->currentIndex())->toInt();
    Champ c = champObjects[vectorIndex];
    // do whatever you want with it
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answers both of You! I'll try it out though, I never used vectors. So I'm not totaly understanding this. Is there any simplier way to do this without using vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Use Qt's DOM components to do all the parsing and tree building for you (see the examples [here](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/examples-xml.html) for their use).

For the `QComboBox`, once the `QDomDocument` is complete you can search for all your `Champ` nodes and read the `Name` attributes off of them.  For each one, just use `QComboBox::addItem(const QString& text)` to add them.

Then connect the `QComboBox::currentIndexChanged (const QString&)` signal to a method in your XML handling class that searches the DOM tree for a `Champ` node with a `Name` attribute that matches it. Once found read off each one of it's child node values (that's the 'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R' values).